# Stripe - "Cannot specify proration date outside of current subscription period"

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, subscription

I am trying to use Prorations to
update the quantity on a subscription, to calculate the cost for the remainder of the year. (subscription is billed yearly)

When I try to follow the docs
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations
I am getting this error

> Cannot specify proration date outside of current subscription period

Can anyone please explain where I went wrong??

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(subId)
const prorationDate = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
// quantity was 3
const items = [
  {
    id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
    quantity: 7,
  },
]
const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
  customer: subscription.customer,
  subscription: license.subscriptionId,
  subscription_items: items,
  subscription_proration_date: prorationDate,
})
```

***Edit:***
This is how i created the subscription at the beginning

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
customer: customer.id,
mode: 'subscription',
line_items: [
  {
    price: priceId,
    quantity: 3,
  },
],
})
```

Comment: What is the value you get for `prorationDate` if you run that code now? Similarly, when does that subscription's current cycle start and end? Your code should work as long as the proration timestamp is within that start end end.

Comment: `prorationDate  = 1662645473`

Comment: I created the subscription earlier today so it will be next year when it ends. ( it is recurring so it will carry on )

Comment: @Pompey I have it working now. How do I know it will do the invoice. I am looking at the dashboard and it shows nothing

Comment: The invoice won't be created until you actually change the subscription. If you are updating the subscription with the API, keep in mind that the {proration_behavior} you use in your update call will affect if and when the prorations are charged to the user https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior